# What does the HTTP 206 Partial Content status message mean and how do I fully load resources?

Tags: html, apache, request, http-response-codes

I have some image tags on a site like this.

```
<img src="img.png"/>
```

When I try to load them they are only half loading. When I checked the request in the network console I see that the response is:

> 206 Partial Content

I googled it and it says that if there is a range set in header, it will be like this. But where are these headers actually set? And how do I avoid this and load the full images?

Comment: Googling "HTTP 206" came up with this: http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Firebug show a "206 Partial Content" response on a video loading request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755168/why-does-firebug-show-a-206-partial-content-response-on-a-video-loading-reques)

Comment: This question should actually be split into two questions, one on what HTTP 206 means and one on how to get apache to not use it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[From user166390’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755372/1591669) to the question [Why does Firebug show a "206 Partial Content" response on a video loading request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755168/why-does-firebug-show-a-206-partial-content-response-on-a-video-loading-reques)

> This Partial Content code (206) *may* be sent from the server when the client has asked for a range (e.g. "give me the first 2MB of video data").
>
> It is vital for downloading data in chunks which avoids fetching unused resources. (I seldom watch a full video online.) Look at the outgoing request for a `Range` header.

Answer (score 11):

It's up to the client to put in another call to get the rest of the data (or the next bit). You don't have to do anything, they'll get the full image eventually, even if it takes several http calls.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly:

The HTTP **`206 Partial Content`** success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded, and the response body contains the requested ranges of data, as described in the `Range` header of the request.

If there is only one range, the `Content-Type` of the whole response is set to the type of the document, and a `Content-Range` is provided.

If several ranges are sent back, the `Content-Type` is set to **`multipart/byteranges`** and each fragment covers one range, with `Content-Range` and `Content-Type` describing it.

([From Mozilla's excellent HTTP status code reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206))

Next:

HTTP headers set on resources are usually set by the web server. However if the file is large, like a video file [the browser can request a chunk](https://serverfault.com/questions/571554/what-does-http-code-206-partial-content-really-mean) of the resource that is being loaded. Usually a **`HTTP 206`** header will be returned from a client initiated request. The headers set on resources in apache are set in the `mod_headers` section of the `httpd.conf`. Look for the following line to see if partial content is turned on:

```
Header set Accept-Ranges bytes
```

This section controls the behavior of headers set by apache so it will be a good place to start.

Setting the headers can however be done in a number of different ways. For example when using apache you can control the images that are loaded so that they will cache. This can be done using the `[a2enmod module][2]`. This will reduce the load on your server.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem when loading fonts from different subdomains. In my case I was getting 206 due to crossdomain issues and I solved it just by putting a .htaccess file in my root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is this ngix configuration or apache httpd config?

Comment: @Omer this is for apache