# 206 Partial message displayed when child theme is activated. How to tackle this?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

my site is http://web.guru99.com/

in this website i had activate parent theme.

and i had another website – http://wordpress.guru99.com/

wordpress.guru99.com this site is clone site developed with the help of duplicator.

i had actvated child theme here – wordpress.guru99.com.

but in firebug some files loaded partial 206 message is displayed.

So what is the issue with my child theme.

enfold parent theme version – 1.7

child theme downloaded from parent theme website. so i think no any issue with child theme.

so how to tackle this issue.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787380/what-is-206-partial-content to get a better understanding of the code. Might be something the server of theme is requesting to get only partly.

Comment: i had checked but how to tackle this? Any way?

Comment: Figure out which files are requested that way. It's not so much an error as it is a normal response to a certain request. Find the lines of code where these files are being requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download ready made enfold child theme.. just copy following link and paste into your browser's address bar...

**https://kriesi.at/files/enfold-child.zip**

if you want to create custom one, then check following link.

**https://vimeo.com/67221517**