# Partial Content 206 status code when loading an image

Tags: html, http

I have a site that has multiple images being displayed on a page.

These are all varying in size but are in the region of 9MB-15MB.

They are all loading fine except for one. I get a 206 Partial content status.

I have done some research and found on StackOverflow a couple of questions relating to this, but they talk about [it in relation to loading a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787380/what-is-206-partial-content). But my problem is with an image.

The annoying thing is that all other images are loading just fine, even ones from the same directory and the same page.

Things, that I have checked:

- The image is definitely there in the directory.
- The image has full 777 privilege as does its folder.
- It is 10.6MB, but as I have said, I have other images of this size and bigger which are loading with no problem.
- I am able to open the image on the computer (as I am on my local).
- Image is being loaded in a standard img tag.

Answer (score 0):

This should only happen if you are sending a `Range` header in your HTTP request. Does this happen, too, if you are using another browser? If so, this is probably some sort of misconfiguration or bug on the server side. If not, your browser seems to be messy, then I would try to delete the cache or, if this doesn't help, to restart.

Comment: Why wouldn't it happen on any other picture, some of which are bigger?

Comment: Hi @AntonyD'Andrea, have you got any resolution for this? I am facing the same situation now :(

Comment: @Chakri Sorry, I can't remember.

Comment: I found my fix, I faced this problem only with images that are transferred using FTP service of mine where, few bytes are missing.