# HTTP Request returns status 206 partial content, but bootstrap min.css file not loading to browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, request, http-response-codes

We are facing some strange issue with chrome and firefox. our website is not loading the bootstrap.min.js file. Some times is loading some time is not. I try to figure out the issue but i didn't get any solution for it.

It's also showing the **status 206 partial content**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txvmq.png)

Comment: [**What is 206 partial content**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15787380/1407478) more mysterious if chrome or FF not is caching this file ...

Comment: No it's not caching the file.