# 206 - partial content status while loading mp3 file

Tags: html, playframework

I am using the audio tag to play the audio mp3 recordings. Some of the files are giving 206 partial content. It is playing fine in normal players.

> Request Method: GET Status Code: 206 Partial Content

```
Response Header:

Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.mp3
Content-Length: 17472
Content-Range: bytes 0-17471/17472
Content-Type: audio/mp3
```

What should I do to solve this?

suggest any solutions

Comment: Read more https://httpstatuses.com/206

Comment: how can i  generate the multiple content-range..

Comment: A solution to what? A `206` is not an error, but a successful content delivery. So what is your problem if it is playing fine in normal players?

Comment: it is not playing in my  player

Answer (score 1):

`206 partial content` response should be OK (like a 200).
It is used to download streamed data in **chunks**. This way, it avoid sending the whole data each time.

It's up to the client to send a request for the rest of data, but you shouldn't care about because it is resolved **automatically**.

To go further:

- [What does the HTTP 206 Partial Content status message mean and how do I fully load resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787380/what-is-206-partial-content)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206