# Service Worker Failed to execute 'put' on 'Cache'

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a web app that stores the data in the browser to support working "offline".

Below is the code in concern:

```
function getPosCacheData(request, cacheName) {

var storageUrl = request.url;

var checkResponse = navigator.onLine;

return caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
    if (checkResponse == true) {
        return fetch(request).then(function(networkResponse) {
            if (networkResponse.ok == true) {
                cache.put(storageUrl, networkResponse.clone());
            }

            return networkResponse;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            return cache.match(storageUrl).then(function(response) {
                if (response)
                    return formFilter(response);
                else
                    return fallPosBackResponse('live');
            });
        });
    } else {
        return cache.match(storageUrl).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
                return response;
            } else {
                return fetch(request).then(function(networkResponse) {
                    if(networkResponse.ok == true){
                        cache.put(storageUrl, networkResponse.clone());
                    }

                    return networkResponse;
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    return fallPosBackResponse('css');
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

The code above raises this **error**:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'Cache': Partial response (status code 206) is unsupported
at service-worker.js
```

The research I did about this error mentions that clearing the cache solves this error, but unfortunately it didn't work.

I do appreciate your kind help fixing this error.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to store a Response object with a status code of 206.  This is forbidden by the cache_storage spec.  See step 6 here:

https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#cache-put

A 206 status code indicates that only a part of the response body has been returned from the server.  Normally a server only does this if the request included a `Range` header.  See:

[What does the HTTP 206 Partial Content status message mean and how do I fully load resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787380/what-does-the-http-206-partial-content-status-message-mean-and-how-do-i-fully-lo)

You could change your code above to check for requests with a `Range` header and then create a new request without the offending header.  This will result in storing the entire response in cache_storage instead of trying to only store a partial response.  Since you can return a full response to satisfy a range request this should work fine when you are offline.

Comment: Thank you Ben for your help.
I've just noticed that if I refresh the browser the error goes away. (sometimes I need to refresh it 2 times). Do you have an interpretation for this?

Comment: It's possible you are getting a full 200 response from the http cache.  In theory you could check this in devtools or a netlog.

Comment: Thanks Ben. 
This is how I created the new request:
const myRequest = new Request(request.url);
myRequest.headers.delete('range');

Answer (score 1):

fetch(event.request, **{cache: "no-store"}**)

Did the job for me.