# TypeError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'Cache': Request scheme 'app'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, vite

My service worker is throwing this error when I run the app:

[image]

My app's stack is: Vite + Electron, I think I need to disable service worker in vite.config.ts, but I don't know how.

Comment: A lot of errors can have multiple possible causes.  Not knowing anything about your app, and only having the error message itself, we can only guess.  Might as well google the error and see what possible solutions show up.  Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323598/) help?

Comment: unfortunately no. I tried to google but nothing worked. What files should I provide code for?