# Can you specify error with HTTPS-206 response?

Tags: java, http, client-server, server-response

I have this use case, where sometimes the code might be partially successful.
Can I return the response in such case were I respond with `HTTPS-206`, saying,"There was an internal server error in following cases."?

Does 206 code spec, specifies not to mention/ does not allow me to mention `internal server error` in response?

Comment: The status code 206 (Partial Content) is defined in [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1) if you want to read the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP 206 status code (like all status codes in the 2xx range) represents "successful" fulfillment of the request, so if you are trying to represent a partial failure, it would probably not be the best choice. 206 is about the *response* and generally is in response to a request that uses a range header (in other words, a request for only *part* of a resource).
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55330328/639520 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#206_partial_content for more details.

If there has been an error processing the request, you're best to use a 4xx or 5xx response status code, depending on whether the problem stems from client/request data or something truly internal to the server.