# html5 video tag and http 206 partial content

Tags: video, html5-video, mp4

I am trying to load in a video tag an mp4 file.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Video</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <video src="video2.mp4" autoplay="true" controls="true"></video>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I have returned 206 partial content and I am not be able to see anything. What may be the problem?

The video url is: 
http://michelepierri.it/examples/video/video2.mp4

Thank you.

Comment: may be this can help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755168/why-does-firebug-show-a-206-partial-content-response-on-a-video-loading-reques

Comment: I observed the same and found that a browser add-on was interfering. Once disabled videos played just fine.