# Video seek not working in Chrome

Tags: html, azure, html5-video

I am trying to embed a video from an Azure storage blob using the html5 `video` tag. When viewing the embedded video in Chrome the video seek doesn't work (issue only happens in Windows, works fine in OSX), but when viewing the resource directly, seeking works fine.

[direct resource](http://apmmediastoragedev.blob.core.windows.net/media-vid/YfKPFgi39S5nV275.mp4)

[embedded video in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DM9Gc/)

In the jsFiddle, the embedded code is copied directly from the source html generated when viewing the resource directly.

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
    <source src="http://apmmediastoragedev.blob.core.windows.net/media-vid/YfKPFgi39S5nV275.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Do you face the same problem in another browser?

Comment: According to w3schools, in chrome should work fine: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio - FF, IE, and Safari all work fine. Opera has a similar issue where seek doesn't work when you first play the video, but if you refresh the page it does work. All the browsers I tested have html5 support and play the video fine, but the scrubbing/seeking just doesn't work in Chrome/Opera (Chrome only doesn't work in Windows, works fine when tested in OSX)

Comment: try to open the following link on the environment that didn't work (chrome *nix SO): http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all

Comment: It looks like you're not using HTTP Byte Serving. See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032796/seekbar-not-working-in-chrome/21037196#21037196

Comment: Edge also has an issue with seek