# HTML5 video tag loop not working in chrome. But it is working in firefox. How can solve this

Tags: html, html5-video

Here I used loop attribute to play this video in a loop. But in chrome the video plays and stops at the end of the video. It is not working in a continuous loop in chrome browser. It works in Mozilla Firefox.

```
<body>
    <section id="home" style="height: 110%;">
    <!--section added-->
        <video id="video" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop>
        <!--video tag added-->
            <source src="main-video.webm" type="video/webm" />
            <!--video added-->
        </video>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post the full URL to the video? Sounds like you may not have the server configured correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032796/seekbar-not-working-in-chrome/21037196#21037196

Comment: I've seen numerous other questions related to this so I'm sure you have seen those already. but my question is have you seen this test page and made sure you've got everything the same? - http://www.ca-bc.com/links/video/2.html

Also as brianchirls mentioned, it absolutely could be related to a server configuration like mentioned here as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088364/html5-video-will-not-loop

Answer (score 0):

Pass the "muted" attribute and it will start working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).