# I get many 206 partial content

Tags: php, apache, error-code

I have a client application that sends the data to a php file (hosted on Apache). Usually this works without any problem. On a client site I get 206 partial content every time the client app sends data.

The data size is 10 - 30 kB so it is not huge.

If you have any suggestion - like changing Apache settings .. or something similar I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an issue. Any 2xx code means "Success". You can view details @ [Why does Firebug show a "206 Partial Content" response on a video loading request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755168/why-does-firebug-show-a-206-partial-content-response-on-a-video-loading-reques)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The idea is that the client app sends data to a php file and if the data is incomplete (it is a json) than it is not processed.