# Can HTML-Background-Video jQuery plugin work with remote video URLs?

Tags: jquery, html, azure-media-services

I'm trying to use this plugin but all examples use a video that's local to the site. I'm trying to use a video that's on Vimeo or YouTube. Is it possible to use this plugin with an HTTPS streaming video URL?

Plugin site is here: https://github.com/Victa/HTML5-Background-Video

This is what my code looks like, note that the domain/video URL in this example is not real, but for the purpose of an example. I am pointing it at an Azure media services URL, but I've tried a number and it doesn't seem to matter. My questions is, should this work, or is it me? No errors are being thrown in script, and the request for the URL is returning with a 206 - Partial Content HTTP response.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').videoBG({
        position: "fixed",
        zIndex: 0,
        mp4: 'https://somesite.net/somevideo.mp4’,
        ogv: 'https://somesite.net/somevideo.ogv’,
        webm: 'https://somesite.net/somevideo.webm’,
        poster: 'images/christmas_snow.jpg',
        opacity: 1,
        fullscreen: true,
    });
})
```

Comment: what does your code look like

Comment: Updated with code and more detail on the remote URL. Perhaps it's an issue with the way the script is working with Azure Media Services?

Comment: Starting to think this has to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755168/why-does-firebug-show-a-206-partial-content-response-on-a-video-loading-reques  but I have no idea on how to resolve it.

Comment: [This may be some help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787380/what-is-206-partial-content) - looks like it is the plug-in

Comment: Ok what's weird is that it works find if I modify the plugin demo file and use my URL, but when I include it in my own page, which is totally different, it doesn't render the video. The network response codes are identical, so I don't think the 206 is an error, it's correct and working properly. Question is why it's not rendering in my custom page.

Comment: could be a cross domain issue, which would explain the example all using local media